# Gizp column using ActiveModel::Type::Binary

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activemodel

I'm trying to gzip base64 encoded data to store in postgres using the ActiveModel::Type::Binary library.

```
create_table :documents do
  t.binary :document_data
end
```

my model:

```
class Document < ApplicationRecord
  class DocumentData < ActiveModel::Type::Binary
    def serialize(value)
      super compress(value)
    end

    def deserialize(value)
      super decompress(value)
    end

    private

    def compress(value)
      ActiveSupport::Gzip.compress(Base64.decode64(value))
    end

    def decompress(value)
      Base64.strict_encode64(ActiveSupport::Gzip.decompress(value))
    end

  end

  attribute :document_data, DocumentData.new
end
```

The `serialize` method seems to work as expected, however when `deserialize` is called the `value` is not encoded in the same way and `Gzip.decompress` fails.

Thanks for your help.

**EDIT**:

I found in [`ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQL::OID::Bytea#deserialize`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/oid/bytea.rb#L6) does not invoke `PG::Connection.unescape_bytea` if the record is `Type::Binary::Data`. I've called `PG::Connection.unescape_bytea` before `decompress` and it works, but I'm not pleased with this solution, so I'm leaving this open for now.

Comment: Shouldn't that be ```ActiveSupport::Gzip.decompress(Base64.strict_encode64(value))``` instead...

Comment: Moreover I feel, it has to be vice versa instead. ```ActiveSupport::Gzip.compress(Base64. strict_encode64(value))``` and ```ActiveSupport::Gzip.decompress(Base64. decode64(value))```

Comment: hi @VamsiKrishna the data I am receiving is base64 encoded, I want to base64 decode first before storing it in the db to reduce the size of the column.